# Play 2.6 and Ebean's multi DB sources not working

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.6

I have 2.6.5 version of Play and multimodule (several sbt submodules) configuration. I set up 2 different datasources and have Ebean error:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: models.common.defaultStorage.PromoBlock is NOT an Entity Bean registered with this server?
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.createQuery(DefaultServer.java:1019)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.find(DefaultServer.java:975)
    at io.ebean.Finder.query(Finder.java:157)
    at models.common.defaultStorage.PromoBlock.findByProjectId(PromoBlock.java:84)
```

**This happens only when I set up 2 datasources and appropriate mapped class settings** in `application.conf`.

My `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val common = (project in file("modules/common")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)

lazy val admin = (project in file("modules/admin")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean).dependsOn(common)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean).aggregate(common, admin).dependsOn(common, admin)
```

My ebean entities live in `common` module. I have only one `application.conf` in the `root` project and 2 datasources:

```
db {
    default.driver = org.postgresql.Driver
    default.url = "postgres://..."

    mssql.driver = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    mssql.url = "jdbc:sqlserver://..."
}

ebean.default = ["models.common.defaultStorage.*"]
ebean.mssql = ["models.common.mssqlStorage.*"]
```

I found out that if I comment out second `ebean.mssql` option than everything is OK. But with two different lists of mapped class I got exception.

I tried use every instrution from docs https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.5/JavaEbean but still no success.

My `plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.6.5")

...

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "4.0.3")
```

P.s. I'm migrating project from 2.4 (and previously 2.3) version of Play where everything was OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, i have opened a PR on the play-ebean projet.

In our project we set up a workaround. But we are using Java version of Play2 and Guice. I don't know how to apply this solution in Scala.
In the Module class, we have bind the DefaultEbeanConfig.EbeanConfigParser to our own class.

```
bind(DefaultEbeanConfig.EbeanConfigParser.class).to(CustomEbeanConfigParser.class);
```

Code for this class :

```
@Singleton
public class CustomEbeanConfigParser extends DefaultEbeanConfig.EbeanConfigParser implements Provider<EbeanConfig> {


    private final Config _config;

    @Inject
    public CustomEbeanConfigParser(Config config, Environment environment, DBApi dbApi) {
        super(config, environment, dbApi);
        this._config = config;
    }

    @Override
    public EbeanConfig parse() {
        DefaultEbeanConfig ebeanConfig = (DefaultEbeanConfig) super.parse();

        Map<String, ServerConfig> serverConfigMap = ebeanConfig.serverConfigs();
        for (Map.Entry<String, ServerConfig> entry : serverConfigMap.entrySet()) {
            entry.getValue().setDefaultServer(entry.getKey().equals(ebeanConfig.defaultServer()));
        }

        return ebeanConfig;
    }
}
```

As you can see, we use the parse method of the provided parser, and after the parse, we fix the "defaultServer" attribute.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in latest version of play-ebean module that sets all configured datasources as default. Pull request was opened at Sep 6 but it's still not merged.

https://github.com/playframework/play-ebean/pull/125